# Где хранятся файлы модулей питона?

Tags: python

Я очень долго копался в папках питона и на англоязычном стаковерфлоу. Нашел вопрос схожий с моим но всё же моя проблема не решилась а именно - я не могу вызывать импорт модуля если файлы модуля хаотично не разбросаны в каталоге с кодом.

Раньше я кидал файлы в папки libs и lib и всё работало. Сейчас сменил компьютер и не получается.
вот к примеру библиотека - чтобы использовать библиотеку телебот мне приходится хранить её прямо в папке с питоном
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Вот вам нужно разобраться с окружениями и т.д. Вполне может быть, что ставите вы библиотеки в одно окружение, а питон запускаете из другого. С этим нужно разобраться и понять как там всё, другого пути нет.

Comment: [Здесь ты получишь базовую информацию](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/rabota-s-modulyami-sozdanie-podklyuchenie-instrukciyami-import-i-from.html) Внимание прошу уделить sys.path, а далее ищи в гугле по ключевым словам из статьи, так у тебя получиться разобраться с окружениями.

Comment: похоже вы вообще не используете виртуальное окружение (virtual env), а копируете исходники (?) зависимостей прямо в проект. Почитайте про virtual environment - это то что вам нужно